# To build war file combine with front end and back end project

Tags: maven, npm

The apps contains two projects, front end and back end.

Front end build by npm and back end build by maven.
How to build this in one war file.
Now my solution is build separate. and use command the combine in one war file.

Answer (score 0):

See [Maven Standard Directory Structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).  As per maven, you will have to put your files in appropriate directories shown in the above link if you have to integrate both your front end and back end.

What you can do is, with the existing maven project that you have, add all your front end code in `src\main\webapp` directory and build one single `war` file. 
Adding your front end code to `src\main\webapp` will include all your front end files (such as html, css, js) on the classpath.